# how to join table using lambda in repository pattern

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i have repository which is :

```
     public class RepositoryTest<T>:IRepositoryTest<T> where T:class
{
    private CentralEntities db = null;
    private DbSet<T> table = null;
    public RepositoryTest() {
    this.db = new CentralEntities();
    table = db.Set<T>();
                        }
    public RepositoryTest(CentralEntities db)
    {

        this.db = db;
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {           
        return table.Where(predicate).ToList();

    }

}
```

its signature is in the following interface:

```
  IEnumerable<T> SelectAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

in my controller im using it to get data for a table and it works:

```
      IRepositoryTest<UserRoles> _repository = null;
    public DashbrdController(IRepositoryTest<UserRoles> _repository)
    {

        this._repository = _repository;
    }
    public DashbrdController()
    {

        this._repository = new RepositoryTest<UserRoles>();


    }
    public ActionResult DashBrd()
    {
        var rslt = _repository.SelectAll(s=>s.user_id==username);          
        return View(rslt);

    }
```

now the problem is if i want to join this table with another table name it(courses) on user_id,first of all i need to add that class in my repository?and controller?and then how to join it ?

Comment: Can't you join using `Include` ?

Comment: @Haytam the problem is how to add another table(class) from my model to this controller to do the join or include!?

Comment: Well the Include works on properties of the class so you don't need to add other classes to your repository.

Comment: can you please make and example here?according to my class?

Comment: Can you add your class code please? and the other tables (assuming they are in UserRoles).

Comment: UserRoles is one table,i want to join it with Course,on user_id